# Differential amplifier for current measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, solenoid, current-sensing

I'm studying reference design from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu578/tidu578.pdf) (pdf).This design shows the solenoid control circuit. I was interested, why a differential amplifier is used to measure the current? Why not use non-inverting circuit op-amp?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A differential input with Kelvin connection from shunt to amplifier will reject noise much more effectively than a single-ended input. I think this is the main reason. If it were single ended, some common mode noise might couple onto the trace. With differential pair routing, noise will most likely couple onto both traces equally and be rejected by the amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Because high currents flowing through the sensor resistor may flow to the GND pin of the opamp, and induce measurement errors.

Comment: Because of GND R34 and GND U2A can have different potentials.
Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Close. GND R43 and GND R7 can have different potentials.